# Sequence of arithmetic expression

Tags: r

I need to generate an arithmetic sequence but am unable to get my head around it. `cf` is a 20x20 matrix. I am copying the first couple of lines of the matrix. I am trying to write a program to create spot rates using bootstrapping.

```
head(cf)
# [3,] 4.25 4.25 104.25   
# [4,] 4.50 4.50   4.50 104.50    
# [5,] 5.50 5.50   5.50   5.50 105.50    
# [6,] 4.75 4.75   4.75   4.75   4.75 104.75
```

`Price` is a vector of bond prices at each period.

```
bond_data$Price
# [1]  96.15  92.19  99.45  99.64 103.49  99.49
```

For the 3rd period, which is the 3rd row in `cf` the calculation looks something similar to this:

```
Z[3] = bond_data$Price[3] - CF[3,1]/(1+z[1]/2)^1 - CF[3,2]/(1+z[2]/2)^2
```

For 4th period which is the 4th row  in the CF matrix the calculation looks something similar to this:

```
Z[4] = bond_data$Price[4] - CF[4,1]/(1+z[1]/2)^1 - CF[4,2]/(1+z[2]/2)^2 - CF[4,3]/(1+z[3]/2)^3
```

`Z[1]` and `Z[2]` are known values, I am trying to generate `Z` for only a couple of periods to start with and this is what I wrote:

```
for(for k in 3:5){ 
  seq( from = (cf[k,1]) / (1+(z[1]/2))^1, to = (cf[k,k-1])/(1+(z[k-1]/2))^k-1 )
}
```

This is not working as I thought it would. Not sure where my logic is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you should say what you're actually trying to do and what `price` and `cf` are.

Comment: so is the denominator of each term always `(1+z[j]/2)^j` ?  If so, you don't want a `seq` but rather a **sum** over a loop from 1 to `k` . maybe `price[k] - sum(for(j in 1:k) cf[k,j]/(1+z[j]/2)^j)`

Comment: excellent idea , let me try that